# @Html.Sitecore.Field is not rendering any values

Tags: mvc, controller

In this code model, fields are returning value but when I try to render using @Html.Sitecore().Field its returning null.For experience editor, these fields should be editable.How to do it?

Am new to Sitecore any help or suggestion is much appreciated

```
        @using Sitecore.Mvc
        @using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation
        @using Sitecore.Data

       @model Project.Service.Models.Model
      <div>
      <h1>@Html.Sitecore().Field("Property Name")</h1>

      <h4 class="text-danger"><em>
      <span itemprop="streetAddress"> @Model.ProvinceName</span>,
      <span itemprop="addressLocality">@Model.CityName</span>,
      <span itemprop="addressRegion">@Model.ProvinceName</span> 
      @Model.PostalCode</em></h4>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`@Html.Sitecore().Field("Property Name")` only works when your model is `Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel`. You are using a custom model.

To use it in your case, you will need to pass in the item like this.

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Property Name", Item)
```

In your case, you would need to pass in the datasource item. Your model would look like this, notice the InnerItem property and the EditableField property.

```
namespace Project.Service.Models
{
    using Sitecore.Data.Items;
    using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation;

    public class Model
    {
        public string ProvinceName { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public Item InnerItem { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then you data call would look like this, returning the model to your view

```
public Model GetModel()
{
    var datasourceItem = RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item;
    return new Model
    {
        ProvinceName = datasourceItem["Province Name"],
        CityName = datasourceItem["City Name"],
        PostalCode = datasourceItem["Postal Code"],
        InnerItem = datasourceItem
    };
}
```

Then in your view you would get the Item from your model with the innerItem.

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("City Name", Model.InnerItem)
```

Comment: How to pass an Item I tried this syntax it returns null value only

Comment: Answer updated to show the new model and the data calls.

Comment: Thanks for great information.Please clarify me few doubts.                              
   ---->About accessing city name am I need to use 
        @Html.Sitecore().Field("City Name", Item).                                    
  --->what does Editable field really do?

Comment: If you just want the value of "City Name". Then just do @Model.CityName. If you want an editable field do @Html.Sitecore().Field("City Field", Model.InnerItem). The only difference between the two is Model.CityField is just the value of your model while @Html.Sitecore().Field("City Field", Model.InnerItem) is an actual editable field from a field called "City Field" on your datasource item. Hope that helps. If you dont want an editable field, just keep using Model.CItyField.

Comment: Output for my Rendering Context: RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item      Also I am not getting any values in INNERITEM   model element                                                                                           

 Home (en#1@master), id: {DD2083AF-2FCD-4C7F-8A7D-F32FC5607DA2}
    Database: "master"
    Id: "{DD2083AF-2FCD-4C7F-8A7D-F32FC5607DA2}"
    Language: "en"
    Name: "Home"
    Version: "1"

Comment: I have updated the answer to be a little less abstract. Let me know if that helps. Long and short of it, it use @Html.Sitecore().Field("City Name"), your model needs to be `Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel`. If you want to continue using a custom model and @Html.Sitecore().Field("City Name"). You will need to add the item to your model and then pass that item in as a parameter. i.e. @Html.Sitecore().Field("City Name", Model.InnerItem)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74276/discussion-between-chris-auer-and-sitecore-u9).